# Unable to find negative numbers for Longest Decreasing Sequence

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I wrote an assembly code combined with C. It only works if the numbers in the array are positive numbers. If I want to test any negative numbers, it skips the numbers.

Here is my assembly code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

; LSD
bestIndex dword 0
bestLen dword 0
curIndex dword 0
curLen dword 1
i dword 1
strLSD byte "Longest Decreasing Sequence: ", 0
strBestIndex byte "Begins at index ", 0
strBestLen byte " and has a length of ", 0

.code

findLDS proc C arr:sdword, len:dword
;arr - array passed from C
;len is the length of the array

mov ecx, len
mov esi, arr
add esi, type arr

compare:
    .IF i <= ecx
    jmp cont
    .ELSE
    jmp ex
    .ENDIF

cont:
    mov eax, dword ptr [esi - type arr]
    .IF dword ptr [esi] <= eax
    jmp incCurLen
    .ELSE
    jmp setCurLen
    .ENDIF

incCurLen:
    inc curLen
    jmp compareCurLen

setCurLen:
    mov curLen, 1
    mov eax, i
    mov curIndex, eax
    jmp compareCurLen

compareCurLen:
    mov eax, bestLen
    .IF curLen > eax
    jmp changeBest
    .ELSE
    jmp incI
    .ENDIF

changeBest:
    mov eax, curIndex
    mov bestIndex, eax
    mov eax, curLen
    mov bestLen, eax
    jmp incI

incI:
    inc i
    add esi, type arr
    jmp compare

ex:
    ; when our loop ends, print the sequence
    mov ecx, bestLen
    mov ebx, bestIndex
    mov edx, offset strLSD
    call writestring

    L1:
        push ecx
        mov esi, arr
        mov eax, dword ptr [esi + type arr*ebx]
        call writeint
        mov al, ','
        call writechar
        mov al, ' '
        call writechar
        inc ebx
        pop ecx
        loop l1

call crlf
mov edx, offset strBestIndex
call writestring
mov eax, bestIndex
call writedec

mov edx, offset strBestLen
call writeString
mov eax, bestLen
call writedec

call crlf
ret
findLDS endp

END
```

Here is my C code:

```
int main()
{

int arr[] = { -5, 10, 20, 80, 73, 32, 20, 22, 19, -5 };
int len = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
findLDS(arr, len);

return 0;
}
```

**Output for this array:**

Longest Decreasing Sequence: +80, +73, +32, +20. Begins at index 3 and has a length of 4

Which is correct, but if I change my array's 20 (index 6) to -20, my output is

Longest Decreasing Sequence: +80, +73, +32. Begins at index 3 and has a length of 3

Comment: Do not use `.IF`, write out the `cmp` and the appropriate conditional jump. The `.IF` may be generating unsigned comparison when you want signed.

Comment: @Jester I will try and report back

Comment: I wouldn't make `i` a static variable.  You need it in a register to use as an array index or pointer anyway.  Seems like it would just create a bunch of unnecessary loads/stores.  It's not like you ran out of registers inside your loop; keep things in registers when possible, prioritizing ones that change all the time or are used as part of addressing modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Jester, I changed it to signed cmp and it works.

Code:

```
cont:
    mov eax, dword ptr [esi - type arr]
    cmp dword ptr [esi], eax
    jle incCurLen
    jmp setCurLen
```

Comment: You can also change `.IF dword ptr [esi] <= eax` to `.IF sdword ptr [esi] <= eax`. `SDWORD` is the signed version of DWORD.